# Class extending itself?

Tags: php, oop, syntax

I encountered a PHP class written by a previous employee that is defined like this:

```
namespace SomeNamespace;

class SomeClass extends ::SomeClass
{
    private function __construct() {}

    public static function someFunction()
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Would somebody please explain what is going on here? Is this class extending itself? I know a singleton would use a private constructor, but not sure that is what is happening here.

The actual class has to do with caching. Not sure if that helps.

Comment: does it execute without errors? and are you sure that both classes are in the same namespace?

Comment: Good question! Never seen code like that before.  Either the previous employee was a genius, or a crazy person.

Comment: I am reluctant to execute the class at this time. But, yes! There is a line which defines a namespace above the class definition (I updated the question to reflect this).

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM, expecting T_STRING or T_NAMESPACE or T_NS_SEPARATOR in /data/sandbox/g/8d06c.php on line 2

Comment: @genesis: `T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM`? That's an odd error.

Comment: @You: It is that double-double : before SomeClass ( :: )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can do this kind of thing using **`::`** ; but it should work if you are using the namespace separator : **`\`**

I just tested with PHP PHP 5.3.5 -- and using `::` does indeed get me an error.

Using \, on the other hand, works just fine *(see example below)*.

For example, being in the global namespace *(outside of any specific namespace)* you could define a class `SomeClass` :

```
namespace {

    class SomeClass
    {
        public function method() {
            var_dump("child: " . __METHOD__);
        }
    }


    $obj = new SomeNamespace\SomeClass();
    $obj->method();

}
```

And, in a specific namespace called `SomeNamespace` in my example, you could define a class `SomeClass` that would extend the class from the global namespace -- which is accessible as `\SomeClass` :

```
namespace SomeNamespace {

    class SomeClass extends \SomeClass
    {
        public function method() {
            var_dump("parent: " . __METHOD__);
        }
    }

}
```

Sidenote : Here, I've use the [bracketed syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definitionmultiple.php), as I'm putting the two portions of code in the same file *(see Example 3 on that manual page)* -- but it should work just the same with several files.

---

Note that with the first alpha versions of PHP 5.3, the namespace separator was not `\`, but `::`

So, if you are using PHP 5.3 alpha 1 or 2 *(and maybe 3, not sure if `\` has been choosen before or after alpha 3)*, using `::` might work.

*(Of course, you should not be using an alpha -- especially considering that there have been stable versions of PHP 5.3 for two years now)*

Comment: Yes! We are running an alpha version of PHP. We don't need to comment about that now :-)

Comment: Ergh, you really really really should not run on an alpha -- especially such an old one! The day you switch to a stable version, all your namespace code will break... *(sorry, I couldn't resist commenting ^^ Glad I could help, though)*

Answer (score 2):

If I'm remembering correctly during the development of 5.3 `::` was used as the namespace separator.